# How to remove the blank element in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I've the following implementation.

```
Array.prototype.abc = function(condition, t){
    var arr = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        arr.push(condition(this[i],t));         
    }
    return arr;
};

var a = [1,2,3,4];
var t = 2;

alert(a.abc( function(item,diviser){
    if(item % diviser === 0) { return item; }
},t));
```

The result should be `[2,4]`. Instead I'm getting `[,2,,4]`.

I've tried the following conditions but it always returns the above result.

```
if(condition(this[i],t) !== false){ arr.push(condition(this[i],t)); }
```

This I'm doing when I do

```
if(item % diviser === 0) { return item; } else { return false; }
```

The `false` condition doesnot work for `'false'` or `true` or `'true'` or for that matter any value I return in else part. In the actual implementation I do not have the `else` part though. I know we can use `splice` or something to remove the blank sections. But I do not understand even if i don't return anything why blank in being created. And even after using if condition before `arr.push` it does not work. What exactly is happening and how to remove the blanks in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check whether the returned value is `undefined` or not from your `callBack`,

```
for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
  var x = condition(this[i],t);
  if(typeof x !== "undefined") arr.push(x);         
}
```

You have made 2 different attempts to fix this but that will fail because,

1. `!== false`, your callBack will return either a number or undefined. So the strict equality will fails all the time and will be evaluated to false always since the operand's types are different.
2. `if(item % diviser === 0) { return item; } else { return false; }` This will return false when the condition fails and hence `false` will be pushed into the array. And it will not skip that pushing part.

Comment: I tried comparing with `!== false` when i return `else{ return false; }`. But this doesn't work. why is that so?

Comment: @Sp0T Careful about this snippet, `condition(this[i],t) && arr.push(this[i]);` This would ignore `0` if it is there in your main array.

Answer (score 0):

Move the cmondition outside of the push and place it before. The condition should only return true or false.

```
condition(this[i],t) && arr.push(this[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a push regardless of what `condition` is returning.

Replace this

```
arr.push(condition(this[i],t));
```

with

```
var val = condition(this[i],t)
val = val !== false && arr.push(val);
```

Since your `condition` method is explicitly returing false, you can simply check for `val !== false`

DEMO

```js
Array.prototype.abc = function(condition, t){
    var arr = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
       var val = condition(this[i],t); console.log(val);
       val !== false && arr.push(val);
    }
    return arr;
};

var a = [1,2,3,4];
var t = 2;

document.body.innerHTML += a.abc( function(item,diviser){
    if(item % diviser === 0) { return item; } else { return false; }
},t);
```